# Script Not Running

Tags: java, linux, startup

I have a script file that I would like to run whenever my computer starts up. What the script file does is run a .jar file that I have on my desktop.

I first created a .jar file called **Hello.jar** that is located on my desktop. After that I created a script file **(.sh)** called **Script.sh** that has the following contents in it.

```
cd Desktop;java -jar Hello.jar;
```

Then I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245128/need-to-run-a-sh-as-root-on-boot-or-login) answer to run the file on startup. So as it says I first setup a .desktop file by running this command in the terminal.

```
sudo cd Desktop
sudo mv Script.sh /usr/bin
```

Then I did

```
sudo cd /usr/share/applications
sudo gedit file.desktop &
```

Then I wrote the following information in gedit.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hello.sh
Exec=/usr/bin/file.sh
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

And lastly I created a copy of it in this location.

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

I then restarted my computer but nothing happened.

Comment: cd Destktop is hazardous... Better use java -jar ~/Desktop/Hello.jar

Comment: Looks like a question for [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo cd` doesn't do anything! The `cd` command only takes effect within the current shell - which immediately exits!

Instead you should do `sudo bash` to launch a root shell. Then run all your commands within that root shell.

Also, I think you forgot to give your script execute permissions. You can do that by changing `mv` to `install`.